# Probability of x favorable events out of y possible ones, with z number of rolls

Tags: probability

There is a bowl with 20 coins, each coin has a number on them, going from 1 to 20.

You pick 5 of them at random.

What is the probability that the numbers 1, 2 and 3 will have been picked, out of the total 5?

I didn't know how to approach this question. If it were just 3 picks, I think it would have been:

`1/((3/20)*(2/19)*(1/18))`

But with 5 picks, I don't know how to calculate it.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, the order in which you get the numbers doesn't matter, if you get `1, 18, 3, 2, 11` it's still a "winning" pick, so is `12, 1, 2, 3, 14` and `1, 2, 3, 5, 8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a note to OP: when I say "order is important", it's just an assumption you *can choose* to make when answering a probability question because that's another way of getting to the same answer; it's not because the order is actually important. But what *is* important is that if you assume order is important for the denominator, then you have to assume order is important for the numerator as well. Alternatively, if you assume order is not important for the denominator, then you have to assume order is not important for the numerator as well.

OP wants to treat $17, 20, 4, 3, 11$ the same as $3, 11, 20, 17, 4$, (i.e. the order is not important) so I'll answer the question with this assumption first.

The total number of possible events is: $ = \frac{20 \times 19 \times 18 \times 17 \times 16}{5!} = 15504 $.

Then for the total number of ways of picking $1,2,$ and $3$, remember when counting that $ 1,17,7,3,2 $ is the same as $ 17,2,3,1,7 $. So let's list the different combinations you want:

$1,2,3,4,5$ (same as $1,2,3,5,4$).

$1,2,3,4,6$ (same as $1,2,3,6,4$).

etc.

There are $16 + 15 + ... + 3 + 2 + 1 = 8.5 \times 16 = 136$ possible combinations of these. Note that $136 = \frac{272}{2}$.

So total probability is $\frac{136}{15504} = \frac{1}{114}.$

$$$$

Now I'll use the method under the assumption "order is important", or in other words $17, 20, 4, 3, 11$ is *different* to $3, 11, 20, 17, 4$.

Total number of possible events, (where order is important) $ = 20 \times 19 \times 18 \times 17 \times 16 = 1860480$.

Total number of ways to choose the numbers $1,2,3$ out of $5$ "picks" where order is important $= {5 \choose 3} \times 3! \times 17 \times 16= \frac{5!}{3!2!} \times 3! \times 17 \times 16 = \frac{5!}{2!} \times 17 \times 16 = 60 \times 272 = 16320$, because there's $17$ ways for the $4$th number out of $5$ to be not in $\{1,2,3\}$, and there's $16$ ways for the $5$th number out of $5$ to be not in $\{1,2,3\}$.

So total probability is $\frac{16320}{1860480} = \frac{1}{114}.$

Now notice that both methods have similar numbers, and basically the final fraction you get for the second method is $\frac{120}{120}$ times the fraction you get in the first method, owing to the fact that there are $5! = 120$ ways of permuting any 5 chosen numbers.

Comment: Wait, this doesn't really make sense. this would mean that it's a higher chance to get 1,2,3 if it's just 3 picks, than it is if you have 5 picks, which is obviously wrong. For 3 picks it would be 1/(20*19*18), no? Ah I forgot to mention, order is not important.

Comment: I'll give your first comment a think, but "order is not important". Well- you'll get the same answer if you treat both things as order being important, or if you treat both things as order not being important. You'll get the same answer.

Comment: I don't understand how though. On an intuitive level, let's say the first number is 1, if order was important, the second number would necessarily have to be 2, but if order wouldn't be important, the second number could be either 2, or 3, or any other number if 2 and 3 will come up in the later picks.

Comment: Basically I've tried to do: (all possible outcomes where 1,2,3 are in the 5 "picks") divided by (all possible outcomes). Ah, I see where I've gone wrong now. I'll edit my answer now. Ok, I think my answer is still wrong, but I'm getting there. I just wanted to get my answer in first because other people are too fast lol

Comment: By the way the chance of getting 1,2,3 if it's just 3 picks is $ \frac{6}{20\times 19\times 18} = \frac{1}{1140}$

Comment: “order is important” doesn’t mean you have to do it in numerical order. It means 1,11,7 is different to 7,1,11

Comment: One more thing: I don't understand what you did here: $= {5 \choose 3} \times (3! \times 17 \times 16) = \frac{5!}{3!2!} \times 3! = \frac{5!}{2!} \times 17 \times 16 = 60 \times 272 = 16320$ specifically, did you typo and forget the ```x17x16```?

Comment: yeah, good spot. I'll add that in now...

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that matters in determining whether the desired coins are selected is if they belong to the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ or if they do not.  Therefore, your question is equivalent to coloring the coins $\{1, 2, 3\}$ green, and all other coins red, and asking for the probability that if $5$ coins are taken without replacement, that you have $3$ green coins and $2$ red coins.

Consequently, the random number $X$ of green coins selected is a hypergeometric random variable with parameters $$N = 20, n = 5, k = 3$$ such that $$\Pr[X = x] = \frac{\binom{k}{x}\binom{N-k}{n-x}}{\binom{N}{n}},$$ hence $$\Pr[X = 3] = \frac{\binom{3}{3}\binom{17}{2}}{\binom{20}{5}} = \frac{17!}{2! \, 15!} \cdot \frac{5! \, 15!}{20!} = \frac{5(4)(3)}{20(19)(18)} = \frac{1}{114}.$$

Comment: Can we really just color all the numbers $\{1,2,3\}$ green? Even if we got three green coins, this could correspond to two $1$s and a $3$ without the number $2$ appearing?

Comment: @K.defaoite Each coin has a unique combination of color and number, and they are drawn **without** replacement.  This is implied by the sampling scheme of the problem:  you draw $5$ different coins from the bowl at the same time.  Therefore, if the only green coins are $\{1, 2, 3\}$, and the rest are red, it is not possible to observe the outcome you describe.

Comment: Oh right. I misunderstood the original question.